# React JS JSX Show or Hide Based on Another Toggle Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have 2 toggle components that show/hide panels under them which is working fine.  However, If I toggle the second panel I need to make sure the first panel is off. Same with the first, I don't want the two panels toggled open at once.

Here is a basic example of what I have.

```
<ToggleControl
    label={__( 'Toggle One' )}
    checked={ toggleOne }
    onChange={ () => this.props.setAttributes({ toggleOne: ! toggleOne }) }
/>

    { toggleOne ?
        <PanelBody>
            ... Show Panel 1 Stuff
        </PanelBody>
    : null }

<ToggleControl
    label={__('Add Image Divider')}
    checked={toggleTwo}
    onChange={() => this.props.setAttributes({ toggleTwo: !toggleTwo })}
/>

    { toggleTwo ?
        <PanelBody>
            ... Show Panel 2 Stuff
        </PanelBody>
    : null }
```

I can toggle the other panel inside the onChange() of the other toggle by doing this...

```
onChange={() => this.props.setAttributes({ toggleTwo: !toggleTwo, toggleOne: !toggleOne })}
```

But I don't want to toggle it if its already off and can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI: according to https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html, props are read-only.  "Whether you declare a component as a function or a class, it must never modify its own props."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn off a panel, you can just set the toggle variable to `false`.

To turn off the first panel when toggling the second panel, you can do the following:

```
onChange={() => this.props.setAttributes({ toggleTwo: !toggleTwo, toggleOne: false })}
```

Similarly, to turn off the second panel when toggling the first panel, you can do the following:

```
onChange={() => this.props.setAttributes({ toggleOne: !toggleOne, toggleTwo: false })}
```

This will make sure that when toggling one panel, the other one is always off, so that you will not have both panels toggled on at the same time.

Comment: This makes sense, short and sweet, TY!

Answer (score 1):

[Edit: Props are read-only, and while my original answer and the accepted answer were identical and do the trick, I'm adjusting my answer to show the "proper" way to do it through manipulating state, not props.]

I don't know why you're tracking the changes on `this.props` instead of `this.state`<s>, but here is one way</s>:

*To be added in constructor:*

```
this.state = { toggleOne: this.props.toggleOne, toggleTwo: this.props.toggleTwo }
```

For Toggle One:

```
onChange={ () => this.setState({ toggleOne: !this.state.toggleOne, toggleTwo: !this.state.toggleOne ? false : this.state.toggleTwo }) }
```

For Toggle Two:

```
onChange={ () => this.setState({ toggleTwo: !this.state.toggleTwo, toggleOne: !this.state.toggleTwo ? false : this.state.toggleOne }) }
```

*And of course set the `checked` attributes to `this.state.toggledOne/Two`.*

Logic:

1. Set ourselves to our opposite state.
2. If our current state is off (false) and we're toggled on (!false), turn our neighbor off (false); if we're switching from on to off, leave our neighbor where they are (which in most cases will be off because we were just on).

My additional true/false check at the end vs. the default of `false` in the accepted answer is meant to catch the case that both toggles were opened on purpose (i.e. programmatically). This may not ever be the case for your scenario, but for others looking for a similar solution who may want this feature, there you have it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.